# Add marquee to TextView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, marquee

I have a `RecyclerView` that has an `ImageView` and a `TextView` in it.

Since the text inside the `TextView` might be long, I had like it to scroll continuously.

The items inside the `RecyclerView` are as follows: (I wrote the same long text inside all of them just to show an example)

[image]

The xml for the TextView is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagecard"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="1111111222222223333333" />
```

and in my Adapter for the `RecyclerView`:

```
tv_Link.setSingleLine();
tv_Link.setSelected(true);
```

Thing is that when the RecyclerView is loaded, the text is not moving. Only if I move to another activity and then return to that layout it shows the text moving.

How can I make sure that it will move right when the RecyclerView is loaded and not only when moving between activities?

Thank you

The complete XML of this layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/imagecard"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Image"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imagecard"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imagecard"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagecard"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightPurple"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagecard"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_A"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it move, try this :

```
 tv_Link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 tv_Link.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
 tv_Link.setSelected(true);
 tv_Link.setSingleLine(true);
```

In your XML :

```
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_Link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagecard"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    android:text="1111111222222223333333"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Sorry mate didnt work. It just made the text disappear

Comment: @Ben I've tested right now, and it's worked just fine, could you please add the entire XML code of your item

Comment: added the complete xml mate. From my understanding, it doesn't work since there are more than one textviews that should move in that same recyclerview, and instead of showing it just makes text disappear. It does work when I use on single textview but not inside recyclerview.